# Should menu having a drop down menu in it point to a page?

Tags: html, menu

I am developing a website with drop down menu. I was thinking if the parent menu should also point to a location or just point to the same page?

Here is the visual,
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming I understand your question correctly) you never want to have menu items that don't go anywhere (or go anywhere different).  If it's redundant and you want to send that link to the same place as one of it's children, then you should take a menu item out, and if it's a parent of menu items, then make a summary/landing page for that category where you list the child menu items along with an explanation.